# Is there an easier way to filter out rows from multiple CSV files and paste them into a new csv file? IM having issues doing that using a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, filter, concatenation

```
#Purpose: to read CSV files from every every csv files in the directory. Filter the rows with the column that say 'fail" from the csv file. Then copy and paste those rows onto a new CSV file. 


# import necessary libraries
from sqlite3 import Row
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import csv

# Writing to a CSV
# using Python
import csv


# the path to your csv file directory.
mycsvdir = 'C:\Users\'' #this is where all the csv files will be housed.

# use glob to get all the csv files
# get all the csv files in that directory (assuming they have the extension .csv)
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, '*.csv'))
   

# loop through the files and read them in with pandas
dataframes = []  # a list to hold all the individual pandas DataFrames
for csvfile in csv_files:
    
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    dataframes.append(df)

    #print(row['roi_id'], row['result']) #roi_id is the column label for the first cell on the csv, result is the Jth column label
dataframes = dataframes[dataframes['result'].str.contains('fail')]
    # print out to a new csv file
dataframes.to_csv('ROI_Fail.csv') #rewrite this to mirror the variable you want to save the failed rows in.
```

I tried running this script but im getting a couple of errors. First off, i know my indentation is off(newbie over here), and im getting a big error under my for loop saying that "csv_files" is not defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dataframes = pd.DataFrame(), don't make it a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

The first one is kind of easy - The variable in the for loop should be csvfiles, not csv_files.

The second one (Which will show up when you fix the one above) is that you are treating a list of dataframes as a dataframe.

The object "dataframes" in your script is a list to which you are appending the dataframes created from the CSV files. As such, you cannot index them by the column name as you are trying to do.

If your dataframes have the same layout I'd recommend using df.concat to join all dataframes into a single one, and then filtering the rows as you did here.

```py
full_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
full_dataframe = full_dataframe[full_dataframe['result'].str.contains('fail')]
```

As a tip for further posts I'd recommend you also post the full traceback from your program. It helps us understand exactly what error you had when executing your code.

Comment: thank you for your response, so with that being said, should I not be using the the variable dataframes as a list anymore and instead use it as an empty data frame variable instead? Or keep the list and just use the concatenation instead.

Comment: pd.DataFrame.append is deprecated since pandas version 1.4.0, so I would recommend going with the pd.concat route instead. Also, if this answer solved your issue don't forget to accept the answer.